# Grails and mongo DB nesting data structure

Tags: json, mongodb, grails, grails-domain-class, database

I have a Grails project the interacts with mongo DB. I would like to know what is the best practice for creating domain classes that represent nesting data.

data for example:

```
settings:{
  user:{id:1234 , name:"john"}
  colors:{header:"red" , footer:"white"}
}
```

would appreciate any help or code examples

Answer (score 0):

I think it is reasonable to presume that you are using mongodb plugin.

To put it simple:

```
Class Settings {
    int user_id
    String user_name
    String colors_header
    String colors_footer
}
```

If there is a legacy mongodb collection like you presented:

```
Class User {
    int id
    String name
}
Class Color {
    String header
    String footer
}
Class Settings{
  User user
  Colors colors
  static embedded = ['user','colors']
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm using the plugin. I'm a bit confused, If I use your first example, how is the nesting hierarchy preserved upon get query? could you give a code example?

Comment: The first definition is not nested, but a simplified , flatened structure. If you want nested data, just take the second one, which matches you legacy data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Since MongoDB is completely schemaless it means you are not limited to a fixed number of columns like in a relational database. so it fairly easy to create nesting data.

here is an example:

```
//the domain class
class Settings {
    Map user
    Map colors
}
```

---

```
//in the groovy controller
def s = new Settings(user: [name:"jhon"],colors:[header:"red" ,footer:"white"] )
s.save(flush: true)
```